# Hibernate vs DB Table Constraints

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

Good time.

Say, there are two DB tables: **FOLDERS** and **FOLDER_TYPES**.

```
CREATE TABLE FOLDERS (  
  ID               VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)   NOT NULL, 
  NAME             VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE) NOT NULL, 
  DESCRIPTION      VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
  FOLDER_TYPE_ID   VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL, 
  PARENT_FOLDER_ID VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) 
)

CREATE TABLE FOLDER_TYPES ( 
  ID          VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL, 
  NAME        VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL, 
  DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)
)
```

As you can see there is a **NOT NULL contraint** in the **FOLDERS** table on the **FOLDER_TYPE_ID** column.

The Hibernate's entities for these tables are the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "folders")
public class Folder implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1856858081142422000L;

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
   @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
   @Column(name = "[ID]")
   private String id;

   @Column(name = "[NAME]")
   private String name;

   @Column(name = "[DESCRIPTION]")
   private String description;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "folder_type_id")
   private FolderType type;

   ...
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "folder_types")
public class FolderType implements Serializable{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = -7992732910184226857L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "[ID]")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "[NAME]")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "[DESCRIPTION]")
    private String description;
```

**The problem is:** when I remove a Folder object, before the actual deletion from the DB, Hibernate tries to set a null value to the reference (folder type), but there is the constraint, so an exception is thrown. As a workaround I can remove the constraint, but what if it is required to have it, and I can't alter the table (**FOLDERS**)?

Is there a way to say Hibernate not to update the entity to null references? I've tried setting `updatable = false` to the `@JoinColumn` (FolderType type) in the Folder entity, but there has been no luck...

Comment: you could force it to use default value: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126610/how-can-nhibernate-use-the-database-default-value-when-saving-a-new-entity

Comment: Well, I think it is not the case, because the folder_type column is actually a foreign key (by means), that is why there is no default value. But, thank you for the idea =)